# duplicating jQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

The `datepicker` function only works on the first input box that is created.

I'm trying to duplicate a datepicker by cloning the `div` that is containing it.

```
<a href="#" id="dupMe">click</a>
<div id="template">
  input-text <input type="text" value="text1" id="txt" />
  date time picker <input type="text" id="example" value="(add date)" />
</div>
```

To initialize the datepicker, according to the [jQuery UI documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker) I only have to do `$('#example').datepicker();` and it does work, but only on the first datepicker that is created.

The code to duplicate the `div` is the following:

```
$("a#dupMe").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  i++;
  var a = $("#template")
            .clone(true)
            .insertBefore("#template")
            .hide()
            .fadeIn(1000);
  a.find("input#txt").attr('value', i);
  a.find("input#example").datepicker();
});
```

The strangest thing is that on the `document.ready` I have:

```
$('#template #example').datepicker();
$("#template #txt").click(function() { alert($(this).val()); });
```

and if I click on the `#txt` it always works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend just using a common class name as well.  However, if you're against this for some reason, you could also write a function to create date pickers for all text boxes in your template `div` (to be called after each duplication). Something like:

```
function makeDatePickers() {
  $("#template input[type=text]").datepicker();
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I use a CSS class instead:

```
<input type="text" id="BeginDate" class="calendar" />
<input type="text" id="EndDate" class="calendar" />
```

Then, in your `document.ready` function:

```
$('.calendar').datepicker();
```

Using it that way for multiple calendar fields works for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had a very similar problem which after hours of testing I found a solution. I was copying a block of HTML code and inserting it after a section that already contained a jQuery date picker calendar.  What I failed to realize at first was the jQuery UI calendar modifies the class of the element when executing the `.datepicker()` function. The result is when you try to copy the code and initiate a new instance of the calendar for that new section it fails because the according to the CSS there already is one. If you attempt to use `.datepicker('destroy')` this fails to destroy this ghost instance because it doesn't actually exist. I solved the problem by resetting the class of the date picker element in my HTML then adding the datepicker to that element...

Below is the code I was using. Hopefully this saves someone else some time...

```
$('#addaddress').click(function() {
  var count = $('.address_template').size();
  var html = $('.address_template').eq(0).html();
  $('#addaddress').before('<div class="address_template">' + html + '</div>');
  $('.address_template H1').eq(count).html("Previous Address " + count);
  $('.address_date').eq(count).attr("class","address_date");
  $('.address_date').eq(count).attr("id","movein" + count);
  $("#movein" + count).datepicker();
});
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the sample code, but  you've got a good point - you need to remove the `.hasDatepicker` class before you can reinitialize a datepicker. Then reinitialize datepicker on the cloned element, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The html I am cloning has multiple datepicker inputs.

Using Ryan Stemkoski's answer and Alex King's comment, I came up with this solution:

```
var clonedObject = this.el.find('.jLo:last-child')
clonedObject.find('input.ui-datepicker').each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).removeClass('hasDatepicker');
    $(element).datepicker();
});
clonedObject.appendTo('.jLo');
```

Thanks yall.