# Script not working with new versions of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, html-table, addition

This simple script, to add / delete tablerows using jQuery works well with version 1.3.2. however, on the same pages I am also using scripts that need jQuery > 1.6. This script doesn't work with that anymore, because if i click add the second time, it removes a row instead of adding it.

A working example can be found here: http://jsbin.com/arete3/edit#source

```
$(function(){
        $("input[type='button'].AddRow").toggle(
            function(){
                $(this).closest('tr').clone(true).prependTo($(this).closest('table'));
                $(this).attr("value", "Delete row");
            },
            function(){ 
               $(this).closest('tr').remove();          
        });
    });
```

To see what I mean, change the jQuery version into anything higher that 1.6

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Well, the behaviour with higher jQuery versions is correct. What exactly do you want to happen?

Comment: That code doesn't look like a correct signature for .toggle. http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Baszz:
There is no particular error, but the script becomes useless because it doesn't do anymore what it supposed to do:

http://jsbin.com/arete3/edit#source

1.3.2: When you click the addrow button, it adds a row, you can do this as often as you want. You can also remove the rows you added, with the exeption of the first row. Works like a charm.

>1.3.2 (preferable 1.6.x): You can click the add row button one time, so far it works good. But when you click it another time, it deletes a row instead of adding it. You can also delete the first row this way.

Comment: @AutoSponge Its the _other_ toggle. http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a script that does what your looking for.
I dont know why you are using `.toggle` because one time its adding and the next its deleting. Which is pointless.

[Check out this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ozaqoz/edit#javascript,html)

I think this is what your looking for.

```
$(function(){
// Add row on click (on click of the add button)
$("input[type='button'].AddRow").click(function(){
    // Add the row
    $(this).closest('tr').clone(true).prependTo($(this).closest('table'));
});

// Delete row on click (on click of the delete button)
$("input[type='button'].DelRow").click(function(){
    // Delete the row
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
}); // End DOM
```

Comment: You are changing the markup in that way, you should try to limit the changes when you do this kind of refactoring.

Comment: This also works, thank you. The only thing I am missing here, is that you are able to delete the first row. But that's solved now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could change the script like this

```
$("input[type='button'].AddRow").click(

function() {
    var index = $(this).closest('tr').index();
    if (index > 0) {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    } else {
        $(this).closest('tr').clone(true).prependTo($(this).closest('table'));
        $(this).val("Delete row");
    }

});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/fGam7/

Comment: Is it possible to add some sort of counter in the id of the HTML tags? I am using the jQuery datepicker plugin (jQuery UI) which works on one field, but using this script each field get's the same id.

Comment: @mat of course you can, for example you could use the index as counter to add to your id. I didn't see any id in your example, though

Comment: it's almost like a scriptrequest.. I am good in PHP, but not so mutch in JS and jQuery. I am using your code (as above), the code for the datepicker is:  jQuery('.AddRow').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    }); The result is that all fields get the same date. I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34790/duplicating-jquery-datepicker/1423156#1423156 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365150/dynamic-jquery-date-picker-code but can't get it working.. Do you perhaps have a suggestion?

Comment: @mat you should post your full code, maybe open a new question so that it's easier to help! :)

Comment: > Thank you for your reply. I opened a new topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399631/jquery-clone-tablerow-and-add-datepicker

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the "value" of an element that way.  Use ".val()":

```
$(this).val("Delete row");
```

Starting with jQuery 1.6, the ".attr()" method strictly (well, after 1.6.1, *almost* strictly) deals with actual **attributes**, as opposed to **properties** like "value" on an `<input>` element.  For setting properties, you can use ".prop()" or, in the case of the "value" property in particular, ".val()".

The change made in 1.6.1 was to ease up on the strictness in the case of several boolean attributes/properties like "checked" and "selected".  In my personal experience, it's safer to stick to "prop()" even with those, especially when dealing with radio buttons.

(The distinction between "attribute" and "property" seems subtle, but it really matters, especially in IE. An "attribute" is something stored in the DOM node in its internal map accessed via the "setAttribute()" and "getAttribute()" methods. A "property" of a DOM node is like any other JavaScript object property. So, because to get/set the value of an `<input>` DOM node you'd refer to the "value" property, you use ".prop()" or ".val()" to manipulate it with jQuery. Other important properties are "src", "href", "className", "id", "name", "type", "tagName", etc.)

Also you might want to consider prepending your table rows to the closest `<tbody>` element instead of the `<table>`.